# Kivy Date Countdown

Tags: python, kivy, countdown

Let's say there is an event on 25th of September 2030. Is there a way to create a countdown that counts the amount of days left till its 25th of September 2030 using Kivy Python. If so id appreciate the help.

Comment: If you search for "kivy timer" I'm sure you'll find what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use python to get the current day
(https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/get-current-date-and-time-using-python/)
and then calculate the days left
(there you can use https://www.thecalculatorsite.com/time/days-until.php)
Then you could make a Label with your days left.
(https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.label.html)
I hope these sites help you with your countdown!